# How to send Firebase paswordless login link?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement magic link login to my app. I enabled email login option through Firebase console and localhost is already under the authorized domains. I have the code snippet and the screenshot in the below.

I can see that some request is being done with 200 success code but I receive no email.The code does not throw any error and I have no idea what is wrong at this point. Can someone help?

```
export const sendMagicLink = (email: string, redirectUrl: string) => {
const auth = getAuth(getClientApp());
const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: redirectUrl,
    handleCodeInApp: true
};
return sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings);};
```

```
const handleSubmit: svelte.JSX.EventHandler<SubmitEvent, HTMLFormElement> = async ({
        currentTarget
    }) => {
        email = new FormData(currentTarget).get('email') as string;
        const redirectUrl = `${window.location.origin}/auth/confirm`;
        state = 'submitting';

        try {
            await sendMagicLink(email, redirectUrl);
            setMagicEmail(email);
            state = 'success';
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                state = error;
            } else {
                console.log(error);
                state = new Error('something went wrong sending the magic link ');
            }
        }
    };
```

Request body:

```
canHandleCodeInApp  true
continueUrl "http://localhost:3000/auth/confirm"
email   "someemail@gmail.com"
requestType "EMAIL_SIGNIN"
```

[image]

Comment: When using Firebase, I always check the spam folder. But you probably, already did that.

Comment: You were right.. *facepalm*. I found the mails in the spam folder.

Comment: Happens all the time ;-) If you want to avoid this problem, register a custom domain and use a proper SMTP server for sending out emails from Firebase. Relying on Firebase for sending these emails may classify them as spam.

Comment: Any chance you can write up those comments into an answer @Dabbel. Spam->custom domain->custom SMTP server is pretty much the standard recommendation we give ourselves, and in a quick search just now I didn't find any answers saying exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively a developer assumes that emails sent out by Firebase's internal email service will not be classified as **spam**, but this happens very often.

To solve this, one would need to:

**Setup a custom domain for Authentication in Firebase Console**

1. Go to **Firebase Authentication**
2. Go to **Templates**
3. Go to **Email Address Verification**
4. Click **Edit**
5. Click **Customize domain** and go through the whole process

**Setup a proper SMTP server in Firebase Console**

1. Go to **Authentication**
2. Go to **Templates**
3. Go to **SMTP Settings** and enter SMTP Settings. Use the same sender domain as has been used in **Email Address Verification** above.

**Setting Action URL**

Set your custom domain in the **Hosting** section, first, e.g.: `example.com`.

Then, in the **Authorization Templates** section, click **Edit** and adjust the **Custom Action URL** at the bottom of the page. Set it to the same domain used for **Hosting**, e.g.:

`https://example.com/__/auth/action`

This helps to decrease the spam ranking of the emails, as the outgoing email from domain A will now contain a link to domain A.

In contrast, an email from domain A carrying a link to domain B is more suspicious.